# How to deal with Foreign Keys into Dimension Tables

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-modeling, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I am trying to separate the following fields into a new *dimension* table called **Territory**.

[image: Power BI Model]

As you can see, there is no `TerritoryKey` in the *Fact Table* I have.

As the columns should not repeat in a *Star Schema*, how can I separate those columns into a new dimension table and then delete the original ones?

Is there any option I can apply with Power Query or SQL?

I tried to call those fields into Order Details (Fact Table), create a new table related to this columns and then delete the columns from the fact table and the Products Table with Power Query.

But if I delete any of this columns, all their fields become null.

Comment: Don't do it. Your data model is ok as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Merging the Product's supplier's attributes on every Product dimension row is the correct star schema design.

Naturally the Supplier would be a snowflake dimension related to the Product.  That's a valid approach too.

But it's not usual to make the snowflake dimension a stand-alone dimension directly related to the fact.